# Is there java.util.Optional.or(Supplier<Optional>) implementation for JDK 8

Tags: java, option-type

I  wanted to find a short implementation for the behavior: return another `java.util.Optional` if the current one is empty.

JDK 9 has the `Optional.or(Supplier<Optional>)` method, but I use Java 8.

Maybe some third party library provides something similar?

Comment: No there are just `.empty()`, `.of(T value)` and `.ofNullable(T value)` in Java 8.

Comment: There is [`public T orElseGet(Supplier<? extends T> other)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#orElseGet-java.util.function.Supplier-) in `Optional` of Java 8.

Comment: @LutzHorn, thanks for your answer. I'm aware of JDK8 Optional methods, I was looking for a third-party implementation for desired behavior.

Comment: It's simple enough to write yourself.

Comment: @deHaar, correct, but it should return the first Optional resolved type.

Comment: OK, then you might have to implement it yourself or google for a third party library (as you already know).

Answer (score 1):

It is easy enough to implement for yourself.

In fact, you can actually make an (arguably) better method, in that the "alternative" optional can be broader if you implement it as a static method:

```
static <T> Optional<T> orElseGet(Optional<? extends T> first, Supplier<Optional<? extends T>> secondSupplier) {
  if (first.isPresent()) {
    // Safe cast, because there are no consumer methods on Optional.
    return (Optional<T>) first;
  }

  // Safe cast, because there are no consumer methods on Optional.
  return (Optional<T>) secondSupplier.get();
}
```

The instance method version of this in Java 9 can only supply an Optional containing a subclass of the receiver's type. This version can return a broader type:

```
Optional<Number> opt = orElseGet(Optional.of(0), () -> Optional.of(0.0));
                              // ^-- Optional<Integer>
                              //                       ^-- Optional<Double>
```

Answer (score 0):

Luckily for you, Java is open-source, so you can look into JDK 9 and check the implementation for `Optional.or()`. From there, it should be easy enough to implement/copy-paste into your project as a static function.